# How to read file from folder in Java Micronaut

Tags: java, json, resources, classpath, micronaut

On a Micronaut project I have a folder structure like the following:

```
myproject
     |____mocks
     |      |_____file.json
     |
     |____src
           |_____main
                   |_____java
                           |_____s.p.d.b.controllers
                                     |________MyController.java
```

I want to read the content of file.json and return it as the response of a GET request handler on MyController.

```
@Controller("${endpoints.all.path}/v1/file")
public class MyController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @Get
    public HttpResponse<List<FileModel>> getAll() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String file = "mocks/file.json";
        String jsonString;
        List<FileModel> fileList;
        try {
            jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
            fileList = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<FileModel>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            return HttpResponse.serverError();
        }
        return HttpResponse.ok(fileList);
    }
}
```

This works locally when running from IntelliJ. It doesn't work once I deploy the application to my K8S cluster. On the deployed app I'm getting an error:
`[default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR c.s.p.d.b.c.MyController`

For some reason the files can't be parsed or are not available to the deployed app. Is there something I need to do to load them or add them to the classpath?

Answer (score -2):

The location of the files was inadequate. I moved them to the resources folder and then I could access them easily.

```
myproject
     
     |
     |____src
           |_____main
                   |_____java
                   |       |_____s.p.d.b.controllers
                   |                 |________MyController.java
                   |
                   |
                   |_____resources
                            |
                            |_______mocks
```

Comment: Is it really `src/resources/mocks/` or is it `src/main/resources/mocks/`?

Comment: FYI... The answer has been updated to clarify that the correct path is `src/main/resources/mocks/`.